# Compare strings based on alphabetical ordering

Tags: python

Write a function that takes two strings as arguments and returns the one which is longer.  If the strings have equal length, return the one that comes first alphabetically.

This is what i have so far:

```
    def strings(x,y):
        if len(x) > len(y):
            return x
        if len(x)==len(y):
            return 
        else:
            return y
```

I am wondering how i would write the code so it would choose the string that comes first alphabetically for the second if statement.

Comment: The incredible thing is that I can't find a duplicate for this.

Comment: It shouldn't have been difficult to find a duplicate. The question is how to compare strings alphabetically (the bit about length is a red herring, since it is already handled), and since *that is what happens by default*, answering the question is equivalent to knowing that it happens by default - therefore, a question detailing the default behaviour is a perfectly satisfactory duplicate. That said, at varying points in Stack Overflow history, there has been an inappropriate bias against "easy" questions which has robbed us of important canonicals.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this should work:

```
if len(x)==len(y):
   return min(x,y)
```

Comment: `sorted(x, y)[0]` would have more clarity as to it's intent, perhaps.

Comment: BTW, be careful when doing this for strings of mixed case.  `min("B","a")` will return `"B"` as coming before `"a"`.

Comment: @kreativitea good point.  To protect against this you could use `min(x.lower(), y.lower())` or following @Martijn Pieters' suggestion `sorted([x, y], key=str.lower)[0]`

Answer (score 16):

You can compare strings directly.  `x<y` means "does x come before y alphabetically?"  So you can replace your second block with:

```
if len(x) == len(y) and x < y:
    return x
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def f(x,y):
    return len(x) != len(y) and max([x,y],key=len) or min(x,y)
```